# SQL Populate a new table from a query

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

​Hi Guys, I am really new to sql so i am sorry if this sounds stupid.

I have a query that shows me all the female drivers from two tables (employee and role each table has 1000 rows in total)

**employee table**

```
    1   Brendon Hayford     Male
    2   Appolonia   Mawer   Female
    3   Stanly  Loachhead   Male
    4   Kinny   Hulcoop     Male
    5   Alyssa  Vose        Female
    6   Gerrie  Cradey      Female
    7   Katalin Coverly     Female
    8   Michelina   Yukhov  Female
    9   Abbey   Thunnerclif Male
    10  Skippy  Juett       Male
    11  Kizzee  Bleythin    Female
    12  Shea    Coxhell     Male
    13  Win Shilstone       Male
    14  Carita  Giddy       Female
    15  Tiebout Creffield   Male
```

**role table**

```
1   Mechanic
2   Admin
3   Mechanic
4   Admin
5   Admin
6   Mechanic
7   Driver
8   Mechanic
9   Admin
10  Driver
11  Admin
12  Driver
13  Admin
14  Mechanic
15  Mechanic
```

**Query**

```
SELECT role.idrole, employee.*, role.role 
FROM employee 
INNER JOIN role 
ON idrole=idemployee 
WHERE role.role="Driver" 
AND employee.gender="Female";
```

this query return 161 rows of female drivers.

```
7   7   Katalin Coverly     Female  Driver
26  26  Jenilee Soeiro      Female  Driver
34  34  Rachel  Tourner     Female  Driver
46  46  Joanne  McCallister Female  Driver
47  47  Maure   Wingrove    Female  Driver
63  63  Bettina Mattecot    Female  Driver
74  74  Nelle   MacRierie   Female  Driver
77  77  Elsinore    Milius  Female  Driver
80  80  Emalia  Hellewell   Female  Driver
82  82  Kerianne    Pirkis  Female  Driver
95  95  Teena   Pesak       Female  Driver
99  99  Harriot Seyffert    Female  Driver
```

I need a way to assign every 2 female drivers from this query to a team (example row 1 and row 2 are in team A row 3 and row 4 Team B etc)

```
7   7   Katalin Coverly     Female  Driver Team A
26  26  Jenilee Soeiro      Female  Driver Team A
34  34  Rachel  Tourner     Female  Driver Team B
46  46  Joanne  McCallister Female  Driver Team B
47  47  Maure   Wingrove    Female  Driver Team C
63  63  Bettina Mattecot    Female  Driver Team C
74  74  Nelle   MacRierie   Female  Driver Team D
77  77  Elsinore    Milius  Female  Driver Team D
80  80  Emalia  Hellewell   Female  Driver Team E
82  82  Kerianne    Pirkis  Female  Driver Team E
95  95  Teena   Pesak       Female  Driver Team F
99  99  Harriot Seyffert    Female  Driver Team F...
```

any info or advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output (as formatted text).

Comment: @HoneyBadger Hi i have edited the original question.

Comment: Can any 2 drivers be in any team / random selection or is it by the order of drivers or do drivers need to be assigned to specific teams?

Comment: I think there's something wrong in your design if that query is true. Why does `idrole=idemployee`? I would expect the table `role` to have one row where `role='Driver'`, and that all employees who are drivers point to that single record.

Comment: @Felix yes a team only needs any 2 female drivers, the drivers can change teams but any team must have 2 female drivers

Comment: @HoneyBadger The role table is linked to employees and is made up of admins, mechanics and drivers. the employees are male and female. the query selects all the female employees who also happen to be drivers. i then need to put 2 female drivers in a team until all female drivers have a team.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Nick Hi im using MySQL workbench 8.0

Comment: @HoneyBadger are you saying my role table should only have 3 rows (Mechanic, Driver, Admin) and then somehow i link each row in the employee table to one of those 3 rows in the role table? if so how would i do that? I have used a random database filler to populate each table with 1000 rows of data.

Comment: @HoneyBadger i thought idrole=idemployee was so that it joined the two tables i.e idrole 1 = idemployee 1 linking row of the two tables.

Comment: Gary if you look at my answer you will see how to implement the `role` table as described by @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 0):

If you're running MySQL 8 inside your workbench version, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate a team number, dividing the row number by 2 to assign 2 people to a team:

```
SELECT r.role, e.*,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY idemployee) + 1) DIV 2 AS Team
FROM employee e
JOIN role r ON r.id = e.idrole
WHERE r.role = 'Driver' AND e.gender = 'Female'
```

Output (based on the data in your question):

```
role    idemployee  firstname   lastname    gender  idrole  Team
Driver  7           Katalin     Coverly     Female  3       1
Driver  26          Jenilee     Soeiro      Female  3       1
Driver  34          Rachel      Tourner     Female  3       2
Driver  46          Joanne      McCallister Female  3       2
Driver  47          Maure       Wingrove    Female  3       3
Driver  63          Bettina     Mattecot    Female  3       3
Driver  74          Nelle       MacRierie   Female  3       4
Driver  77          Elsinore    Milius      Female  3       4
Driver  80          Emalia      Hellewell   Female  3       5
Driver  82          Kerianne    Pirkis      Female  3       5
Driver  95          Teena       Pesak       Female  3       6
Driver  99          Harriot     Seyffert    Female  3       6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qLNEC59PR8LgWjGSTbLX3a/2)

Note that in my demo I have reworked your `role` table to be properly normalised,with an `id` and `role` column; and used a foreign key (`idrole`) in the employee table to refer to the `id` in the `role` table. So `role` looks like this:

```
id  role
1   Mechanic
2   Admin
3   Driver
```

and as you can see from the output above, all the drivers have `idrole = 3`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply by setting a variable and adding a calculation to your SELECT statement. Something like this:

```
SET @var=64;
SELECT field1, ...,
CONCAT('Team-', CHAR(ROUND(@var:=@var+.5))) AS Team
FROM table_name;
```